# Removing duplicates from list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Can anyone suggest a good solution to remove duplicates from nested lists if wanting to evaluate duplicates based on first element of each nested list?

The main list looks like this:

```
L = [['14', '65', 76], ['2', '5', 6], ['7', '12', 33], ['14', '22', 46]]
```

If there is another list with the same element at first position `[k][0]` that had already occurred, then I'd like to remove that list and get this result:

```
L = [['14', '65', 76], ['2', '5', 6], ['7', '12', 33]]
```

Can you suggest an algorithm to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you care about preserving order / which duplicate is removed?  If not, then:

```
dict((x[0], x) for x in L).values()
```

will do it.  If you want to preserve order, and want to keep the first one you find then:

```
def unique_items(L):
    found = set()
    for item in L:
        if item[0] not in found:
            yield item
            found.add(item[0])

print list(unique_items(L))
```

Comment: your conversion to a dict was so much more elegant than mind that I stole it :)

Comment: Doesn't the first one also preserve order because dicts preserve order since Python 3.7 and the keys are inserted in the order that the comprehension produces them?

Answer (score 4):

use a dict instead like so:

```
L = {'14': ['65', 76], '2': ['5', 6], '7': ['12', 33]}
L['14'] = ['22', 46]
```

if you are receiving the first list from some external source, convert it like so:

```
L = [['14', '65', 76], ['2', '5', 6], ['7', '12', 33], ['14', '22', 46]]
L_dict = dict((x[0], x[1:]) for x in L)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Pandas :

```
import pandas as pd

L = [['14', '65', 76], ['2', '5', 6], ['7', '12', 33], ['14', '22', 46],['7','a','b']]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
df = df.drop_duplicates()

L_no_duplicates = df.values.tolist()
```

If you want to drop duplicates in specific columns only use instead:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates([1,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you meant by "another list", so i assume you are saying those lists inside L

```
a=[]
L = [['14', '65', 76], ['2', '5', 6], ['7', '12', 33], ['14', '22', 46],['7','a','b']]
for item in L:
    if not item[0] in a:
        a.append(item[0])
        print item
```

Comment: This would be more efficient if you used a set for 'a' - you're O(N^2) using a list like that, and amortised O(N) using a set.

Comment: that has not come to mind, thanks for the info. nevertheless, that code works in older Python version that doesn't come with set. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the order does not matter, code below

```
print [ [k] + v for (k, v) in dict( [ [a[0], a[1:]] for a in reversed(L) ] ).items() ]
```

gives

> [['2', '5', '6'], ['14', '65', '76'], ['7', '12', '33']]

Answer (score 0):

```
def Remove(duplicate):
    final_list = []
    for num in duplicate:
        if num not in final_list:
            final_list.append(num)
    return final_list

duplicate = [2, 4, 10, 20, 5, 2, 20, 4]
print(Remove(duplicate))
```

Comment: Plase provide some comments about your code and changes you made with the original code.