# Does turning a list into a set, then back again, cause problems in Python?

Tags: python

I'm turning a list into a set in Python, like so:

```
request.session['vote_set'] = set(request.session['vote_set'])
```

So I can easily do a `if x in set` lookup and eliminate duplicates. Then, when I'm done, I reconvert it:

```
request.session['vote_set'] = list(request.session['vote_set'])
```

Is there a better way to do this? Am I potentially doing something dangerous (or stupid)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll lose duplicates if you actually wanted them. If this is actually a list of "votes" as your naming suggests, you'd 'lose' some :)

why not just:

```
if x in set(request.session['vote_set'])
```

if you're worried.

Although I have to wonder if that would be slower than just plain:

```
if x in request.session['vote_set']
```

And ordering, as others have mentioned, would potentially (most likely) be lost.

Comment: Converting to a set (which involves traversing the whole list once) just to test membership once will be slower than testing for membership in the list (which involves traversing the list until a match is found).  If the set is large and you can use it more than once, at some point it will become faster; that's not likely to be the case here though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll lose ordering, if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you remove duplicates AND maintain the order (if you care): [Algorithm - How to delete duplicate elements in a list efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801459/algorithm-how-to-delete-duplicate-elements-in-a-list-efficiently)

The other answers showed how to turn a list into a set.