# Deleting duplicates from a list of lists if some duplicates do not have the same order

Tags: python, list, duplicates

My problem is very similar to the one linked below except that if there was a [2,1] element I would need that to be deleted too.

[Removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

I've tried all sorts of things but just can't make it work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just sort all your sublists and then apply the solution you linked to?

Comment: doh! Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Oh I remember why I didn't think of it, I need the sublists to remain in order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you really want is a *`set` of `set`s*

```
unique = set(map(set, list_of_lists))
```

Edit:  well, but that doesn't work.  alas, sets cannot contain sets because sets are unhashable.  `frozenset` is, though:

```
unique = set(map(frozenset, list_of_lists))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it doesn't preserve the ordering of the sublists:

```
def bygroup(k):
    k = sorted(sorted(x) for x in k)
    return [k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(k)]

>>> k = [[1, 2], [4], [5, 6, 2], [1, 2], [3], [4], [2, 1]]

>>> bygroup(k)
[[1, 2], [2, 5, 6], [3], [4]]
```

In Python 2.7 or 3.2, you could use an OrderedDict if you need to preserve the order within sublists and also the general order of the list (except for duplicates), but it's much slower:

```
def bydict(k):
    s = collections.OrderedDict()
    for i in k:
        s[tuple(sorted(i))] = i
    return s.values()

>>> bydict(k)
[[2, 1], [4], [5, 6, 2], [3]]
```

I tested with 100,000 iterations using timeit. The bydict function took about 4 times longer in Python 2.7.2 and about 3 times longer in Python 3.2.

Comment: Thanks, but alas I need the order of the sublists to be preserved.

Comment: As Tim Pietzcker suggested at the moment I am sorting each sublist as it is created and then am using the fastest method discussed in the question that I linked to. Do you know off the top of your head if your method would be faster than this? (when I have got time I can check for myself).