# Removing duplicates from a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

What is the best way to remove duplicates from a list of lists?

I was trying to use set like this:

```
L1 = [['fox', 'dog'],['bat', 'rat'],['fox', 'dog']]  
L1 = list(set(L1))
```

Unfortunately, I get a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

In my list there are two occurrences of ['fox', 'dog']. I want L1 to remove the duplicate and look like this:

L1 = [['fox', 'dog'],['bat', 'rat']]

Answer (score 9):

If you convert the inner lists to tuples you will be able to add them to a set successfully, for example:

```
>>> set(map(tuple, L1))
set([('fox', 'dog'), ('bat', 'rat')])
```

If necessary, you can get back to lists of lists like this:

```
>>> map(list, set(map(tuple, L1)))
[['fox', 'dog'], ['bat', 'rat']]
```