# conditionals in lambda statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I'm trying to find duplicates in a list by using a lambda function:

```
f = lambda z,y: z=[] if z[0]==y[0] and z[1]==y[1]
```

I have a list like

```
[['hey','ho'], ['hey','ho'], ['howdy','no']]
```

and I would like

```
['hey','ho'], ['howdy','no']]
```

I get the error:

```
>>> f = lambda z,y: z=[] if z[0]==y[0] and z[1]==y[1] else z=z
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to lambda
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes, just trying to ask why python disagrees with the assignment

Comment: This is the solution without lambda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists

Comment: @Falcata Downvotes reflect a perceived lack of research, given that you could have answered the question by looking up the correct syntax for both lambda expressions and conditional expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda needs to be an expression that evaluates to some value. It should not be an assignment to a variable. Get rid of the assignments to `z`.

```
f = lambda z,y: [] if z[0]==y[0] and z[1]==y[1] else z
```

or more simply

```
f = lambda z,y: [] if z==y else z
```

(Strange variable names, by the way. Why `z` and `y`, and why are they backwards?)