# Get intersection of two lists of lists or empty list

Tags: python

I have two lists of lists with same shape.

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [], [4,5], []]
list2 = [[1,2], [7], [4,5], []]
```

I need this list of lists:

```
[[1,2], [], [4,5], []]
```

How I can get it?

P.S.: These topics didn't help me:

[Python - Intersection of two lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101026/python-intersection-of-two-lists-of-lists)

[Find intersection of two nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/find-intersection-of-two-nested-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume each list in `list1` and `list2` contains only distinct elements and you do not care about the ordering of the elements in output, you can use `set` intersection to help you:

```
output = [list(set(l1) & set(l2)) for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: rather humorous timing to get 3 of exactly the same answer

Comment: this just means the problem has a standard answer in Python

Answer (score 4):

Loop through and use sets:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [], [4,5], []]
list2 = [[1,2], [7], [4,5], []]

intersections = [list(set(s1)&set(s2)) for s1, s2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

outputs:

```
[[1, 2], [], [4, 5], []]
```

Answer (score 4):

Get each sub-list by index of the shorter list.

```
[list(set(list1[x]) & set(list2[x])) for x in range(min(len(list1), len(list2)))]
# [[1, 2], [], [4, 5], []]
```

This will result in a list with the same length as the shortest input.

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [], [4,5], []]
list2 = [[1,2], [7], [4,5], []]
new_list = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    inter = [x for x in list1[i] if x in list2[i]]
    new_list.append(inter)

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [], [4, 5], []]
```