# Identify duplicate lists in list of lists?

Tags: python, list

How can I compare a list of lists with itself in python in order to:

- identify identical sublists with the same items (not necessarily in the same
  item order)
- delete these duplicate sublists

Example:

```
list = [ [1, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 12], [9], [3, 1, 5, 6], [12, 10] ]

clean_list = [ [1, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 12], [9] ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: you should avoid built-ins names for your objects like `list`

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thanks for pointing this out, although as stated above it's only a generic example, not an extract of the original script, with obscure variable names that no one would have understood out of context.

Comment: @2ps I'm a Python beginner and didn't know where to begin to tackle the problem. I'm glad that so many people provided helpful answers that I can learn from. Thanks!

Comment: @bdeo I must have overlooked that one. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rebuild the "clean_list" in a list comprehension, checking that the sorted version of the sublist isn't already in the previous elements

```
the_list = [ [1, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 12], [9], [3, 1, 5, 6], [12, 10] ]

clean_list = [l for i,l in enumerate(the_list) if all(sorted(l)!=sorted(the_list[j]) for j in range(0,i))]

print(clean_list)
```

of course, sorting the items for each iteration is time consuming, so you could prepare a sorted list of sublists:

```
the_sorted_list = [sorted(l) for l in the_list]
```

and use it:

```
clean_list = [the_list[i] for i,l in enumerate(the_sorted_list) if all(l!=the_sorted_list[j] for j in range(0,i))]
```

result (in both cases):

```
[[1, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 12], [9]]
```

As many suggested, maybe a simple `for` loop (no list comprehension there) storing the already seen items in a `set` would be more performant for the lookup of the duplicates. That alternate solution could be necessary if the input list is really big to avoid the `O(n)` lookup of `all`.

An example of implementation could be:

```
test_set = set()
clean_list = []

for l in the_list:
    sl = sorted(l)
    tsl = tuple(sl)
    if not tsl in test_set:
        test_set.add(tsl)  # note it down to avoid inserting it next time
        clean_list.append(sl)
```

Comment: can someone explain the downvote? (apart from writing some code for the user)

Comment: Not my down vote, but isn't this a case where a humble `for` loop would be better, checking for the `tuple(sorted(sublist))` in a `set()` of previously seen items?

Comment: SO Things... Sometimes you do your best to help people and a couple of haters downvote your answer anyways.

Comment: @Chris_Rands good point. At least this works :) I don't want to steal it from you, I think you could answer this.

Comment: @gabrielbelini in that case I think the guy downvoted the answer _and_ the question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you, your answer was very helpful. Don't mind the haters. No down vote deserved here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a set. Then for each list in the list, sort it, transform into tuple, then insert into set.

```
setOfLists = set()
for list in listOfLists:
    list.sort()
    setOfLists.add(tuple(list))

print setOfLists
```

You can retransform the tuples in the set into lists again.

Comment: the only issue here: the `setOfLists` won't preserve the order of the sublists. otherwise, OK answer (same as what Chris Rands suggested, except that Chris suggested to keep the set as a marker, but still store the sublists in a list to preserve order)

Comment: also `list.sort()
    setOfLists.add(tuple(list))` => `setOfLists.add(tuple(sorted(list)))`

Comment: also: sorting the sublists may not be what the OP wants. Using an aux set with sorted items would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loops will work, but if your dataset is small, e.g. 1k or less, you can use this :

```
b = []
[b.append(i) for i in a if len([j for j in b if set(j) == set(i)])==0 ]

print b
```

Answer (score 0):

So heres my take on this.

I def a function that sorts each sublist and appends to a temp list. then I check if the sublist in temp_my_list is 'not' in temp_clean_list and if not then append to new list. this should work for any 2 sets of list. I added some extra list to show some kind of result other than an empty string.

```
my_list = [[1, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 12], [9], [3, 1, 5, 6], [12, 10],[16]]
clean_list = [ [1, 3, 5, 6], [7, 8], [10, 12], [9],[18]]
new_list = []

def getNewList():
    temp_my_list = []
    temp_clean_list = []
    for sublist in my_list:
        sublist.sort()
        temp_my_list.append(msublist)
    for sublist in clean_list:
        sublist.sort()
        temp_clean_list.append(sublist)
    for sublist in temp_my_list:
        if sublist not in temp_clean_list:
            new_list.append(sublist)

getNewList()
print (new_list)
```

Resulit:

```
[[16]]
```