# Would like to prevent dupes in a python list of lists

Tags: python

I am creating a list of lists and want to prevent dupes.  For example, I have:

```
mainlist = [[a,b],[c,d],[a,d]]
```

the next item (list) to be added  is `[b,a]` which is considered a duplicate of `[a,b]`.

## UPDATE

```
mainlist  = [[a,b],[c,d],[a,d]]   
swap = [b,a]   

for item in mainlist:
   if set(item) & set(swap):
     print "match was found", item
   else:
     mainlist.append(swap)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can test whether the next item to be added is already in the list?

Comment: Have you attempted this one yet? Would be cool to see your attempt and help you along with difficulties in your implementation.

Comment: Seems like the order within the inner lists doesn't matter so I suggest using a list of `set`s. Then you can simply check `x in list`.

Comment: Even better: a set of frozen-sets. If order isn't important

Comment: Just an FYI: Python has `frozenset`, which can be an element of a set, and `set`, which allows you to test for membership. Maybe a good idea.

Comment: @a_guest I'm not sure that's a fair assumption to make without OP's clarification. For example, we may not want [a, a, b] and [b, a] to be considered the same.

Comment: @Coldspeed damn. No frozen-counter objects... But maybe the OP can clarify on the requirements

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Man, what's with OPs and their lack of clarifications. Sheesh.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.... The each inner lists has 2 elements.

Comment: does the order matter?

Comment: @ChrisJ Can both elements be the same?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, order doesn't matter, obviously, since `{a, b} == {b, a}`. Ideally, use a set of frozensets. We don't need multiset behavior.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh That was exactly my thinking as well. If order _did_ matter, then `[a, b]` shouldn't be a duplicate of `[b, a]`.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I meant the order of the frozensets, i.e., should the outer container be ordered (e.g. a list). As for multisets, that was in case `{a, a, b}` needs to be distinct from `{a, b}`, but the OP already clarified, itis always pairs.

Comment: @coldspeed No the elements in the inner lists can not be the same

Comment: @ChrisJ Your existing code is flawed because even if one element from both sets intersect, you'd still declare a match. You'd essentially want the intersection to be size 2. You can check that with the `len` function.

Comment: #coldspeed I realized that but wasn't sure how to fix it... Not sure how to use the len function to check if the 2 elements in the lists are being compared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using `frozenset`s within a `set` to check for duplicates. It's a bit ugly since I'm invoking a function that works with global variables.

```
def add_to_mainlist(new_list):
    if frozenset(new_list) not in dups:
        mainlist.append(new_list)

mainlist = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'],['a', 'd']] 

dups = set()

for l in mainlist:
    dups.add(frozenset(l))

print("Before:", mainlist)
add_to_mainlist(['a', 'b'])
print("After:", mainlist)
```

This outputs:

```
Before: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'd']]
After: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'd']]
```

Showing that the new list was indeed not added to the original.

Here's a cleaner version that calculates the existing `set` on the fly inside a function that does everything locally:

```
def add_to_mainlist(mainlist, new_list):
    dups = set()
    for l in mainlist:
        dups.add(frozenset(l))

    if frozenset(new_list) not in dups:
        mainlist.append(new_list)

    return mainlist

mainlist = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'],['a', 'd']] 

print("Before:", mainlist)
mainlist = add_to_mainlist(mainlist, ['a', 'b']) # the assignment isn't needed, but done anyway :-)
print("After:", mainlist)
```

---

### Why doesn't your existing code work?

This is what you're doing:

```
...
for item in mainlist:
   if set(item) & set(swap):
     print "match was found", item
   else:
     mainlist.append(swap)
```

You're intersecting two sets and checking the truthiness of the result. While this might be okay for 0 intersections, in the event that even one of the elements are common (example, `['a', 'b']` and `['b', 'd']`), you'd still declare a match which is false.

Ideally you'd want to check the length of the resultant set and make sure its length is equal to than 2:

```
dups = False 
for item in mainlist:
    if len(set(item) & set(swap)) == 2:
        dups = True
        break
   
if dups == False:
    mainlist.append(swap)
```

You'd also ideally want a flag to ensure that you did not find duplicates. Your previous code would add without checking all items first.

Comment: @ChrisJ added an explanation as to why your current code is non-functional.

Comment: _"You'd also ideally want a flag to ensure that you did not find duplicates."_ - Or you could opt to wrap his code in a function and `return` if any of the lists matches `swap`. And if not, add `swap` to `mainlist`. Of course either method would work, but it seemed like a function would be a better choice if only for reuseability-sake.

Comment: @ChristianDean I felt the need to keep that example slightly simple, so as not to introduce too many foreign elements OP might not be comfortable with. Yes, I did consider putting it in a function and returning. ;)

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Nice answer by the way :-) +1

Comment: @coldspeed Man!! so much to learn!! Thanks to you and everyone else

Comment: @ChrisJ Cheers. Enjoy your newfound enlightenment. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the order of your inner lists doesn't matter, then this can trivially be accomplished using `frozenset()`s:

```
>>> mainlist = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'],['a', 'd']]   
>>> mainlist = [frozenset(sublist) for sublist in mainlist]
>>> 
>>> def add_to_list(lst, sublist):
...     if frozenset(sublist) not in lst:
...         lst.append(frozenset(sublist))
... 
>>> mainlist
[frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'d', 'c'}), frozenset({'a', 'd'})]
>>> add_to_list(mainlist, ['b', 'a'])
>>> mainlist
[frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'d', 'c'}), frozenset({'a', 'd'})]
>>>
```

If the order does matter you can either do what @Coldspeed suggested - Construct a `set()` from your list, construct a `frozenset()` from the list to be added, and test for membership - or you can use `all()` and `sorted()` to test if the list to be added is equivalent to any of the other lists:

```
>>> def add_to_list(lst, sublist):
...     for l in lst:
...         if all(a == b for a, b in zip(sorted(sublist), sorted(l))):
...             return
...     lst.append(sublist)
... 
>>> mainlist
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'd']]
>>> add_to_list(mainlist, ['b', 'a'])
>>> mainlist
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'd']]
>>>
```