# Sum and group by values in Python lists?

Tags: python, list

Given a list of lists of form [string, int], say:

```
given_list = [
["adam", 1],["billy", 2],["adam", 3]
]
```

How would you add all integers coupled with each given string to return a list of lists consisting of the set of the strings coupled to the sum of all integers associated with that string?

```
desired_list = [
["adam", 4],["billy",2]
]
```

Comment: this has been answered quite a few times; i'll try to find the dupe

Comment: @TotalNewb2017 this is may be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/python-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists