# How to remove duplicates from nested lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a lists as `list<list<list>>` lists where I want to remove duplicate list.

```
list_1 = [
           [
             [1,2],[2,3]
           ],
           [
             [3,4],[5,6]
           ],
           [
             [3,4], [5,6]
           ]

         ]
```

So expected output should be

```
output = [
           [
             [1,2],[2,3]
           ],
           [
             [3,4],[5,6]
           ]
         ]
```

Is there are shortcut to do that instead of comparing each list with each other. We cannot do set(list_1), then what is the easiest to remove duplicates?

P.S: It's a 3 level nesting so the answer marked for duplicate question doesn't work.

Comment: @pistol2myhead It only works for 2 level nesting, I have 3 level nesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
k = [
           [
             [1,2],[2,3]
           ],
           [
             [3,4],[5,6]
           ],
           [
             [3,4], [5,6]
           ]

         ]

import itertools
k.sort()
list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(k))
[[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

For detailed info you can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213973/4320263

Answer (score 0):

One way I see to it, flatten the list to a lower level and then make this lazy, and at the same time preserve order, by iterating the list of lists and adding to a "`seen`" set:

```
lst = [ [[1,2],[2,3]], [[3,4],[5,6]], [[3,4], [5,6]] ]

from toolz import unique

flat_list = [item for sublist in lst for item in sublist]
res = map(list, unique(map(tuple, flat_list)))
print(list(res))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

**EDIT**:

And if you want the nested lists back, pairing every 2 elements:

```
print([res[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(res), 2)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[5, 6]]]
```