# Add dynamically into a set

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists into map object, if I do:

```
print(my_list)  # map object
print(list(my_list)) # [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1]]
```

and I want to insert them into a `set` object to remove duplicate items.

I know I can do a for, or whatever, but I want to do in one line

I tried:

```
res = my_set.update(x) for x in my_list
```

but I got:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any idea?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO..Have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213973/5236014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
{item for sublist in list(my_list) for item in sublist}
```