# Removing stopwords in a list of a list

Tags: python, list, nlp

I would like to remove the stopwords that are in a list of a list while keeping the format the same (i.e. a list of a list)

Following is the code that I have already tried

```py
sent1 = 'I have a sentence which is a list'
sent2 = 'I have a sentence which is another list'

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

lst = [sent1, sent2]
sent_lower = [t.lower() for t in lst]

filtered_words=[]
for i in sent_lower:
    i_split = i.split()
    lst = []
    for j in i_split:
        if j not in stop_words:
            lst.append(j)
            " ".join(lst)
            filtered_words.append(lst)
```

Current Output of filtered_words:

```py
filtered_words
[['sentence', 'list'],
 ['sentence', 'list'],
 ['sentence', 'another', 'list'],
 ['sentence', 'another', 'list'],
 ['sentence', 'another', 'list']]
```

Desired Output of filtered_words:

```py
filtered_words
[['sentence', 'list'],
 ['sentence', 'another', 'list']]
```

I am getting a duplicate of list. What might I be doing wrong in the loop? Also is there a better way of doing this rather than writing so many for loops?

Comment: Could you add the full function please? What is giving you that output? `filtered_words`?

Comment: It may be helpful if you write out your intended output

Comment: I just made the edits

Comment: what is your `stop_words`?

Comment: its from the nltk.corpus import stopwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is appending `lst` to `filtered_words` each time you find a non-stopword. That's why you have 2 repetitions of the filtered `sent1` (it contains 2 non-stopwords) and 3 repetitions of the filtered `sent2` (it contains 3 non-stopwords). 
Just append after you've examined each sentence:

```
for i in sent_lower:
    i_split = i.split()
    lst = []
    for j in i_split:
        if j not in stop_words:
            lst.append(j)
    filtered_words.append(lst)
```

By the way, the statement

```
" ".join(lst)
```

is not useful, since you're computing something (a string) but not storing it anywhere.

**EDIT**

A more Pythonic way to do this with list comprehension:

```
for s in sent_lower:
    lst = [j for j in s.split() if j not in stop_words]
    filtered_words.append(lst)
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I've just added an optimized version of the code.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a better way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` once you have the duplicated result in `filtered_words` -

```
import itertools
filtered_words.sort()
list(filtered_words for filtered_words,_ in itertools.groupby(filtered_words))
```

The output comes out to be -

> [['sentence', 'another', 'list'], 
>   ['sentence', 'list']]

I followed a link on StackOverflow - [Remove duplicates from a list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired result

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

sent1 = 'I have a sentence which is a list'
sent2 = 'I have a sentence which is another list'

sent1 = sent1.lower().split()
sent2 = sent2.lower().split()

l = [sent1, sent2]

for n, sent in enumerate(l):
    for stop_word in stop_words:
        sent = [word for word in sent if word != stop_word]
    l[n] = sent

print(l)
```