# How to count different elements in list of lists?

Tags: python, list, count

I would like to count the number of unique lists, inside a list of lists.
For instance,

```
>>>list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,2]]

>>>how_many_different_lists(list1)

>>>2 #They are [1,2,3] and [1,2,2]
```

How can I make the how_many_different_lists function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists

Comment: @GaganTK Thank you! I had difficulties searching with English... so I might have missed the results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here`s working code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def how_much_dif_l(arg):
    arg_list=deepcopy(arg)
    i=0
    length=len(arg_list)
    while i<length:
        a = arg_list[i]
        if arg_list.count(a)>1:
            length-=1
            arg_list.remove(a)
        else: 
            i+=1


    return len(arg_list)

list1= [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,2]]
print(how_much_dif_l(list1))
```

Comment: This should not be accepted. You're altering the original list, removing items from it. That's not the best idea.

Comment: @revliscano if you need you can use deepcopy()

Comment: @revliscano completed, officer!

Comment: By the way, cleaning those parenthesis around the if condition and the semicolon after `i += 1` would be a great idea too :-)

Comment: Another thing: I was testing it with another set of data, for example: `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 5]]` and it throws an `IndexError ` That's because the `length -= 1`is placed in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know how many different lists are there, you could simply do:

```
def how_many_different_lists(lists):
    s = set(str(list_) for list_ in lists)
    return len(s)
```

You can call this function as follows:

```
>>> list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,2]]
>>> how_many_different_lists(list1)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
import itertools
lis.sort()
print(list(lis for lis,_ in itertools.groupby(lis)))
```

The above code outputs

```
[[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

You may also do

```
l = []
for i in lis:
    if i not in l:
        l.append(i)
```

Or

```
l = [lis[i] for i in range(len(lis)) if i == 0 or lis[i] != lis[i-1]]
```