# How to remove duplicates in a list containing lists of sets?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am trying to remove the duplicates in the following list. `itertools` did not work here 'cause the internal lists are set instead of integers.

```
[[{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 7}], 
 [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}], 
 [{4, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 7}], 
 [{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
 [{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

my expected output is

```
[[{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 7}], 
 [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}],  
 [{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

anyone knows any methods to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @TomServo the problem with that is that list is not a hashable type. The other answer is probably better

Comment: I have tried the ```itertools``` but it did not work out. The situation here is a little different because elements in the internal list are set instead of integers.

Comment: Why do you have: [{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] in the output?

Comment: Take list  [{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]  as an example, three elements in this list {5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} can be used to cover the universe set = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Comment: What are the duplicates?

Comment: for example [{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 7}] and [{4, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 7}] are two duplicates as well as  [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}] and [{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pprint

data = [[{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 7}],
        [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}],
        [{4, 5, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 7}],
        [{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}],
        [{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]

# find the uniques, keep order of appearance
uniques = dict.fromkeys([frozenset(frozenset(s) for s in e) for e in data])

# transform to original format
res = [[set(s) for s in e] for e in uniques]

pprint.pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 7}],
 [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}],
 [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6, 7}]]
```

The [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) is a hashable version of a set. The function [dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys), keeps the order of appearance in Python 3.6+.