# Count Amount of duplicate Sublists in list with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've been researching for quite some time now but can't seem to find how to do this properly.
I have a List that consists of a sum of 113287 sub-lists, that each hold 2 integers with 2-3 digits each.

```
list = [[123, 456], [111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333], [123, 456], [222, 222], [123, 456]]
```

Now I want to count the amount of sub-lists, that exist more than once.
Not the amount of duplicates overall, also index is irrelevant, I just want to know which combination of values exists more than once.

The result for the example should be "2", since only the sub-lists "[222, 222]" and "[123, 456]" exist more than once.

**If possible and only if it doesn't overcomplicate things**, I would like to do it without external libraries.

I just can't seem to figure it out, any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is your attempt, for loop or something? list is a bad variable name it is colored as you see

Comment: do you want to count [123,456] and [456,123] as two or one each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the elements, then loop over the result to keep only those that have a count greater than 1, and `sum`:

```
my_list = [[123, 456], [111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333],
           [123, 456], [222, 222], [123, 456]]

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(map(tuple, my_list))
number = sum(v>1 for v in c.values())
```

output: `2`

*NB. you need to convert the sublists to tuples for them to be hashable and counted by `Counter`*

Comment: Oh my god that's it. I tried it so many times with Counter, but had things like Counter counting the Values independedly, disrgarding that I grouped them by touple like


"sum(y for y in Counter(tuple(x) for x in list.values() if y > 1)" and many other variations ..  guess I gotta learn Counter a bit more to figure out where my thoughprocess failed.
THANK YOU very much though!

Comment: @mhopfner, seems like you accept this as the answer, please make sure to click the "checkmark" (near the rating) to accept the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `set` of your list. But because lists are unhashable, you'll need to convert each list in `lst` to a tuple. Then simply count the number of times each list in `lst` appears in `lst`:

```
lst = [[123, 456], [111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333], [123, 456], [222, 222], [123, 456]]
out = sum(1 for l in set(map(tuple,lst)) if lst.count(list(l))>1)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Also if you want to count `[[12,34],[34,12]]` as 2, then building off of @mozway's answer, you can do:

```
for i, l in enumerate(my_list):
    if l[::-1] in my_list[:i]:
        my_list[i] = l[::-1]

c = Counter(map(tuple, my_list))
number = sum(v>1 for v in c.values())
```

Comment: using `count` repeatedly is giving bad performance, you'll need to read again the whole list for each existing element. Use `collections.Counter` instead (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251143/16343464))

Answer (score 0):

You can make a non-duplicated version of your list, then count the number of duplicated elements:

```
ls = [[123, 456], [111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333], [123, 456], [222, 222], [123, 456]]
uni = []
c = 0
for l in ls:
    if not l in uni:
        uni.append(l)

for l in uni:
    if ls.count(l) != 1:
        c+=1

print(c)
```

Output: `2`

Answer (score 0):

> MY_LIST = [[123, 456], [111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333], [123, 456],
> [222, 222], [123, 456]]

try this:

from: [Removing duplicates from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

```
uniques = []
for elem in MY_LIST:
    if elem not in uniques:
        uniques.append(elem)
print(uniques,'\n')
```

and then:

```
repeated = {}
for elem in uniques:
    counter = 0
    for _elem in MY_LIST:
        if elem == _elem:
            counter=counter+1
    if counter > 1:
        repeated[str(elem)] = counter

print('amount of repeated sublists: {}'.format(len(repeated)))
print(repeated)
```

output:

```
[[123, 456], [111, 111], [222, 222], [333, 333]] 

amount of repeated sublists: 2
{'[123, 456]': 3, '[222, 222]': 2}
```