# How do I most efficienty check the unique elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, performance

let's say I have a list

```
li = [{'q':'apple','code':'2B'},
      {'q':'orange','code':'2A'},
      {'q':'plum','code':'2A'}]
```

What is the most efficient way to return the count of unique "codes" in this list?
In this case, the unique codes is 2, because only *2B* and *2A* are unique.

I could put everything in a list and compare, but is this really efficient?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+duplicate+list.  Specifically this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143379/removing-duplicates-from-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the most efficient simple way is to create a set of the codes, which will filter out uniques, then get the number of elements in that set:

```
count = len(set(d["code"] for d in li))
```

As always, I advise to not worry about this kind of efficiency unless you've measured your performance and seen that it's a problem.  I usually think only about code clarity when writing this kind of code, and then come back and tighten it only if I've profiled and found that I **need** to make performance improvements.

Comment: FWIW when sets were first introduced in Python this was a novel concept to me. I found it very useful to read up on the math behind sets, which ties it all together: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

Comment: To take the unique of some *group*, it's always O(n), since you have look at every element, unless you have some other inside information.