# Removing duplicates from nested list based on first 2 elements

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a nested list only if the first 2 elements are the same, ignoring the third.

List:

```
L = [['el1','el2','value1'], ['el3','el4','value2'], ['el1','el2','value2'], ['el1','el5','value3']]
```

Would return:

```
L = [['el3','el4','value2'], ['el1','el2','value2'], ['el1','el5','value3']]
```

I found a simple way to do similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143432/1306351):

```
dict((x[0], x) for x in L).values()
```

but this only works for the first element and not the first 2, but that is exactly what I want otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you can use that same method but using a tuple of the first and second elements as the key:

```
{(x[0], x[1]): x for x in L}.values()
```

Or on Python versions older than 2.7:

```
dict(((x[0], x[1]), x) for x in L).values()
```

Instead of `(x[0], x[1])` you can use `tuple(x[:2])`, use whichever you find more readable.

Answer (score 4):

If order matters, use a `set` with only the first two elements of your nested lists:

```
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
return [x for x in seq if tuple(x[:2]) not in seen and not seen_add(tuple(x[:2]))]
```

or you could use a `collections.OrderedDict()` object to keep the order; keep the `x[:2]` slices as keys (as tuples), and extract the values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict(

return OrderedDict((tuple(x[:2]), x) for x in seq).values()
```

In Python 3.6 and up, the standard dict type happens to retain insertion order too:

```
return list({tuple(x[:2]): x for x in seq}.values())
```

The `list()` call is needed to convert the dictionary view object to a list.

Comment: I guess this is a good solution if you _really_ need it to be fast, but in most cases this is just hard to read and unpythonic. Say no to comprehensions with side effects.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: perhaps, but this specific pattern [used to be the fastest method for this specific use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order/480227#480227). If you need the performance, pragmatism beats purity.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
In [55]: dict((tuple(x[:2]), x) for x in L).values()
Out[55]: [['el1', 'el2', 'value2'], ['el1', 'el5', 'value3'], ['el3', 'el4', 'value2']]
```