# tidy up a list and remove duplicates

Tags: python

Hello I want to tidy up this list to keep only the highest result.
Example like: 'M', 'm' and 'O', 'o' are duplicate in the list I want to keep them as their greatest result.

Here is my list :

```py
list_no_ok = [['A', 'a', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  12:46 PM', '8.08'],
           ['B', 'b', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  2:52 PM', '3.46'],
           ['J', 'j', 'In progress', '-', '-'],
           ['K', 'k', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  11:32 AM', '10.00'],
           ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  2:12 PM', '6.15'],
           ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  2:20 PM', '9.10'],
           ['N', 'n', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  3:38 PM', '7.69'],
           ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  5:06 PM', '4.87'],
           ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  5:37 PM', '5.90']]
```

and I want this as output:

```py
list_ok = [['A', 'a', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  12:46 PM', '8.08'],
           ['B', 'b', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  2:52 PM', '3.46'],
           ['J', 'j', 'In progress', '-', '-'],
           ['K', 'k', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  11:32 AM', '10.00'],
           ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  2:20 PM', '9.10'],
           ['N', 'n', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  3:38 PM', '7.69'],
           ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  5:37 PM', '5.90']]
```

The problem is, there is a dash in a list and I don't know how to arrange the list while keeping it.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a dict instead?

Comment: You posted what you want. What **did** you do to get there? How did it not work? [mre]? What is your problem?

Comment: [removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213923/removing-duplicates-from-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: [removing-duplicates-from-list-of-lists-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143379/removing-duplicates-from-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: So the entries are already in order of increasing timestamps? And duplicates appear consecutively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python package `pandas` (https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great way to do this, especially when your 2d list gets very large.

To start we would need to import the package:

```py
import pandas as pd
```

We can put your 2d list in a pandas Dataframe and give it some sensible colums:

```py
list_no_ok = [['A', 'a', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  12:46 PM', '8.08'],
           ['B', 'b', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  2:52 PM', '3.46'],
           ['J', 'j', 'In progress', '-', '-'],
           ['K', 'k', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  11:32 AM', '10.00'],
           ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  2:12 PM', '6.15'],
           ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  2:20 PM', '9.10'],
           ['N', 'n', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  3:38 PM', '7.69'],
           ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  5:06 PM', '4.87'],
           ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  5:37 PM', '5.90']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list_no_ok, columns=["col1", "col2", "status", "date", "value"])
df["value"] = pd.to_numeric(df["value"], errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values(by=["value"], ascending=False)
df
    col1    col2    status       date                        value
3   K       k       Finished     1 October 2020 11:32 AM     10.00
5   M       m       Finished     1 October 2020 2:20 PM      9.10
0   A       a       Finished     30 September 2020 12:46 PM  8.08
6   N       n       Finished     1 October 2020 3:38 PM      7.69
4   M       m       Finished     1 October 2020 2:12 PM      6.15
8   O       o       Finished     1 October 2020 5:37 PM      5.90
7   O       o       Finished     1 October 2020 5:06 PM      4.87
1   B       b       Finished     30 September 2020 2:52 PM   3.46
2   J       j       In progress  -                           NaN
```

Here we have put the 2d list in a Dataframe, gave it column names, we converted the column `value` from string to numbers. We have added `errors='coerce'` for the rows that are still in progress. This will convert the `'-'` to `NaN` (Not a Number). Finally we have sorted it from high to low based on the `value`.

We have sorted it based `value` so that we can make use of the `drop_duplicates` function of pandas:

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'],keep='first')
df = df.sort_values(by=['col1','col2'])
df
    col1    col2    status       date                        value
0   A       a       Finished     30 September 2020 12:46 PM  8.08
1   B       b       Finished     30 September 2020 2:52 PM   3.46
2   J       j       In progress  -                           NaN
3   K       k       Finished     1 October 2020 11:32 AM     10.00
5   M       m       Finished     1 October 2020 2:20 PM      9.10
6   N       n       Finished     1 October 2020 3:38 PM      7.69
8   O       o       Finished     1 October 2020 5:37 PM      5.90
```

Rows get dropped when they have identical `col1` and `col2`. Whenever this happends, it keeps the first occurrence. In this case that is were `value` is the highest since we sorted on `value` before we dropped rows.
We can go back to your `list_ok` by sorting again on `col1` and `col2`.
If you really want to go back to a 2d list that can be done with:

```py
df = df.fillna('-')
list_ok = df.values.tolist()
list_ok
[['A', 'a', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  12:46 PM', 8.08],
 ['B', 'b', 'Finished', '30 September 2020  2:52 PM', 3.46],
 ['J', 'j', 'In progress', '-', '-'],
 ['K', 'k', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  11:32 AM', 10.0],
 ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  2:20 PM', 9.1],
 ['N', 'n', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  3:38 PM', 7.69],
 ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '1 October 2020  5:37 PM', 5.9]]
```

We have used `.fillna` to convert the `NaN` back to the string `'-'`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! but it keeps the smallest value and i want the bigger one.

Comment: Hi bendour, you are right. I made a silly mistake somewhere. Please re-read my answer, I've made some minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to just loop over the list. Hopefully this works for you.

```
list_by_letters = {}

for element in list_no_ok:
    if element[0] in list_by_letters:
        element2 = list_by_letters[element[0]]

        if '-' in element2 or '-' in element:
            continue

        if element[-1] > element2[-1]:
            list_by_letters[element[0]] = element[1:]
            
        continue
    
    list_by_letters[element[0]] = element[1:]

list_ok = [[key]+list_by_letters[key] for key in list_by_letters]
```

Comment: Also, how do you want it to compare between elements that don't have values (the ones with dates) and ones that do?